# dbpedia sparql: foaf name is missing in result but present in resource page

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying a query on http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql

```
SELECT ?name ?fname ?birth ?death ?person ?wikipedia
WHERE {
      ?person dbo:birthPlace dbr:Berlin .
      ?person dbo:birthDate ?birth .
      ?person foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?wikipedia .
      FILTER (?birth < "1900-01-01"^^xsd:date) .
OPTIONAL{      ?person dbp:name ?name . }
OPTIONAL{      ?person foaf:name ?fname . }
OPTIONAL{      ?person dbo:deathDate ?death . }
 } 
ORDER BY ?name
```

In result page if u search  "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Friedrich_Wilhelm_Foerster" under person column, corresponding fname column is empty. 
But if you check http://dbpedia.org/page/Friedrich_Wilhelm_Foerster foaf:name is having value "Friedrich Wilhelm Foerster (en)". Why is this happening and how to resolve the same?

Comment: `foaf:name` is missing on [**live**.dbpedia.org/page/Friedrich_Wilhelm_Foerster](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Friedrich_Wilhelm_Foerster)

Comment: ok..so I was looking at the wrong page. Thanks @Stanislav Kralin